# Creating custom boilerplates in Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, saas, boilerplate

I created an application on Bluemix and I want to create a private Boilerplate from it in order to automatically deploy them when required through a web interface. Is there any possible way to create that boilerplate?

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by private boilerplate? Meaning you do not want the code of your app to be publicly exposed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boilerplates are not public documented, so not possible to create your own in the catalog.

But you can check "[Deploy to Bluemix Button](https://developer.ibm.com/devops-services/2015/02/18/share-code-new-deploy-bluemix-button/)" which perhaps covers your requirement of being able to deploy an app and its runtime and required services.

Comment: I think that would solve the situation. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I think that IBM Containers can be used to achieve that goal. A container is basically an application with all its dependencies, that is stored in a portable, platform-independent module (the container). The structure of a container is explained in an *image*. From a single image you can then instantiate all the containers you want.

So, if you create an image composed by your application and its dependencies and you push it on Bluemix, you can automatically instantiate and deploy new containers (with your application up and running inside) when required through a Web interface as you requested.

IBM Containers are based on Docker containers, that wrap up a piece of software in a complete filesystem that contains everything it needs to run. This guarantees that it will always run the same, regardless of the environment it is running in.

Please refer to [IBM Containers Docs](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_index.html) to understand how to use Docker on Bluemix and [Docker training](https://training.docker.com/self-paced-training) to learn the basics.